# avconv slideshow from images - first image appears for split second

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg, avconv, slideshow

I am currently using the following command to generate a slideshow from all jpg's in the current directory:

`avconv -r 1/5 -f image2 -i %03d.jpg -r 25 -c:v mpeg2video output.mpg`

The command almost works, except that the very first jpg only appears for a split second. All other jpg's in the directory appear for 5 seconds as expected.

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve the glitch?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on the latest 64 bit kernel.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the cause of the issue is but you could solve it by duplicating the first image:

```
cp 001.jpg 000.jpg
```

Then run your `avconv` again and it'll just transition from the first image to the first image. The viewer won't notice the difference.

If your sequence already starts at `000.jpg` that's a bit more painful. We can bump all the existing ones up but we have to write them to a new filename (lest we just overwrite the next one up) and then we can chunk it back to pure numbers:

```
rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf("tmp%03d", $1+1)/e' *.jpg
rename 's/^tmp//' *.jpg
```

Here it is in action:

```
$ rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf("tmp%03d", $1+1)/e' * -v
000.jpg renamed as tmp001.jpg
001.jpg renamed as tmp002.jpg
002.jpg renamed as tmp003.jpg
003.jpg renamed as tmp004.jpg
004.jpg renamed as tmp005.jpg

$ rename 's/^tmp//' *.jpg -vn
tmp001.jpg renamed as 001.jpg
tmp002.jpg renamed as 002.jpg
tmp003.jpg renamed as 003.jpg
tmp004.jpg renamed as 004.jpg
tmp005.jpg renamed as 005.jpg
```